# Java Sudoku solver throws divide by zero ArithmeticException

Tags: java, sudoku

I am doing this Sudoku solver in java, and for some reason I have an error in my code that I just cant fix. My code has a `guess` function where it guesses numbers from 1-9 in each box while it checks if the number is already written before.

The error is in the line:

```
 else if (board[r + (i % 3)][c + (i / 3)] == num)
```

Where i get an `ArithmeticException` (divide by 0) for some reason I can't see why. Hope you can help

My code:

```
public class SudokuSolver
{
final int size = 9;
private int box_size;

private int[][] board;

// Create an empty board
public SudokuSolver()
{
  board = new int[size][size];
  this.box_size = size / 3;

}

// initialize a given board
public SudokuSolver(int[][] board)
{
  this.board = board;
}

public void setCell(int num, int row, int col)
{
  board[row][col] = num;
}

public int getCell(int row, int col)
{
  return board[row][col];
}

private boolean check(int num, int row, int col)
{
  int r = (row / 3) * 3;
  int c = (col / 3) * 3;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
     if (board[row][i] == num)
        return false;

     else if (board[i][col] == num)
        return false;

     else if (board[r + (i % box_size)][c + (i / box_size)] == num)
        return false;
  }
  return true;
  }

  public boolean guess(int row, int col)
  {
  int nextCol = (col + 1) % size;
  int nextRow = (nextCol == 0) ? row + 1 : row;

  try
  {
     if (board[row][col] != 0)
        return guess(nextRow, nextCol);
  }
  catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
  {
     return true;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
  {
     if (check(i, row, col))
     {
        board[row][col] = i;
        if (guess(nextRow, nextCol))
        {
           return true;
        }
     }
  }
  board[row][col] = 0;
  return false;
  }

  public void printBoard()
  {
  for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
  {
     for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
     {
        System.out.print(board[row][col] + "  ");
     }
     System.out.println();
   }

  }



  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

  int[][] board = { { 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 8, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0 }, { 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 8, 0, 0, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 6 }, { 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0 },
        { 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4 }, { 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 },
        { 0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 6, 9, 0, 0 }, { 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 7, 0 } };

  SudokuSolver ss = new SudokuSolver(board);
  ss.printBoard();
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println();
  if(ss.guess(0, 0))
     ss.printBoard();


 }
```

Comment: First port of call: get rid of `catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)` - that exception indicates a *programming error*. You shouldn't be catching it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Looks like a way around real bounds checking.

Comment: @NullUserException: Absolutely. Simply a horrible idea.

Comment: To be blunt I'm skeptical that line throws a divide by zero error.  Please review how you concluded this carefully.

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe the instructor is a fan of EAFP

Comment: @NullUserException: Possibly. In which case, I mourn for the students.

Comment: @JonSkeet Is that because of the cost of exception handling in Java, or are you opposed to the concept itself?

Comment: @NullUserException: The concept itself - for cases where this is a *programming* error. It's entirely reasonable for the caller to have to provide reasonable arguments - and if they don't, they should get an appropriate exception, early.

Comment: I added the entire code so you can see for you self. When i try run it, the the exception comes in the line i wrote about. Somehow i just cant find why it gives that exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing `box_size` before the point at which the error is encountered will reveal that it is in fact `0`. You never initialize it in this constructor, so it retains its default value of `0`:

```
public SudokuSolver(int[][] board) {
    this.board = board;
}
```

You probably meant to include a line like `this.box_size = board.length / 3`.

---

***P.S.*** The *real* line that causes the error is

```
else if (board[r + (i % box_size)][c + (i / box_size)] == num)
```

You probably shouldn't have substituted `box_size` for what you expected it to be in your question.